# Date format on reporting services

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I installed SQL server and reporting services with him, when my regional settings is set to US, date format is been mm/dd/yyyy. Now, I changed region settings to German in tab Formats, Location and also System locale for non unicode programs.

My problem is that when I try to enter parameter for report, datetime format in report manager has same format like before mm/dd/yyyy. I try to re-create database for reporting services but with no luck.

I can not change application to send this us format to reporting services.
Windows server 2012 is OS.

Tnx...

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you can do:

- You can try changing the Language on your report files (Properties - Location - Language) to match the same language on the database.
- When you pass a parameter to a query, instead of using the parameter value, pass it as an expression like this: `=Format(Parameters!Date.Value,"yyyyMMdd")` which will convert it to a date format which will be accepted by any language setting on the database.

Answer (score 0):

This got me for a while - finally found that you have to make sure the data type for the parameter (in the parameter properties) is set to datetime not text.